# Tracking changes to Excel workbook that is being updated with a database. (Unshared Workbook)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a an excel workbook called A.

A is being updated in real time by Database B

We need to track down changes made by users on workbook A.

I have written a code to track down changes made by users.
But since I need the pre-existing value, the Application.Undo function is creating an error because Workbook A is being changed by Database B and not just by users.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Sheets("LogDetails").Unprotect Password:="****"
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & " - " & Target.Address(0, 0)
Application.Undo
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value
Application.Undo
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Environ("username")
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Now
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
Sheets("LogDetails").Protect Password:="***"
End Sub
```

I need to track users changes to workbook A without error from changes to workbook A being made by Database B.

I was thinking if let's say in the IF condition I add 
And Environ("username")= "rogerb"
The code will run only if rogerb has made changes?
What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Idea would work :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Environ("username")="roberb" then
If ActiveSheet.Name <> “logDetails” Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets(“LogDetails”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & “-” & Target.Address(0, 0)
Sheets(“LogDetails”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value
Sheets(“LogDetails”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Environ(“username”)
Sheets(“LogDetails”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Now
Sheets(“LogDetails”).Columns(“A:D”).AutoFit
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End If
End Sub
```